# c# Serialize a class that has a list of elements of the same type as the class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class that is basically a tree structure of the same object (each leaf is always of the same type including the root). Like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public List<MyClass> Children { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Children = new List<MyClass>();
    }

    public void Serialize(string filename)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(GetType());
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.UTF8))
            serializer.Serialize(sw, this);
    }
}
```

When I create an instance of this class with several children to test the Serialize() function, the Children node in the XML is always empty. Why?

Here's an example of initialization:

```
        var test = new MyClass {Property1 = "test"};
        test.Children.Add(new MyClass { Property1 = "child1" });

        var c2 = new MyClass { Property1 = "child2" };
        c2.Children.Add(new MyClass { Property1 = "child21" });

        test.Children.Add(c2);
        test.Serialize("test.xml");
```

In the resultant XML, Children node shouldn't be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
[XmlArray("Children"), XmlArrayItem("MyClass")]
public List<MyClass> Children { get; set; }
```

Did the trick, sorry for the duplicate question